# The argument type 'PointerEvent' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PointerDownEvent'

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, flutter-plugin

Recently I've updated to flutter 2.5 and the newest androids studio, and tried to compile my flutter project to android device. Android studio throws me the error below. If I write `flutter run` in a terminal there is no problem compiling to android device.

Guess this must be related to android studio. I tried downgrade to an earlier android studio version, but the problem persists.

I'm not sure what plugin this is, it doesn't seem like any I use in my project.

Edit: If I downgrade flutter from 2.5 to 2.0 my project compiles again. So the problem is within flutter 2.5

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../plugins/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/photo_view-0.11.1/lib/src/core/photo_view_gesture_detector.dart:106:29: Error: The argument type 'PointerEvent' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PointerDownEvent'.
 - 'PointerEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('../plugins/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
 - 'PointerDownEvent' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/events.dart' ('../plugins/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
    super.addAllowedPointer(event);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There was an API change in version 2.5 of flutter and several packages must update accordingly.
Your logs show that the exact package which contains the error is [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view/changelog).

Luckily enough the package has just been updated to fix this, so just update its version in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
photo_view: ^0.12.0
```

#### UPDATE

###### If you don't have the package directly in your pubspec

You have two options

1 It's probably a transient dependency, you can run `flutter pub deps`
to list the installed packages and its dependencies and try to update the one that uses `photo_view` (if it does have an update)

2 Add a dependency override to your `pubspec.yaml`, this will effectively override the version of the package being used

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  photo_view: ^0.12.0
```

Add this just before your `dev_dependencies`

Comment: I don't have photo_view in my pubspec.yaml

Comment: I am facing the same problem but mine is with `html_editor_enhanced` which includes this  `flutter_colorpicker` as dependency what should I do then

Comment: @AbhishekVishwakarma, the same `dependency_overrides:
  flutter_colorpicker: ^versionWhichUsesNewAPI`. You could try the latest one in pub.dev or check its changelog

Comment: @croxx5f My pubspec is all up-to-date so how can I check its changelog and fix

Comment: @AbhishekVishwakarma in the package page in pub.dev. If you dont find info there then in Github. If after that you dont seem to fix your issue I would encourage you to make a new question

Answer (score 3):

from your debug code
('../plugins/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/events.dart').
you open the file or click if there are link clickable

Search for this:

```
void addAllowedPointer(PointerEvent event) {
```

and replace with this:

```
void addAllowedPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
```

Here is the reference link

https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/gesture-recognizer-add-allowed-pointer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This problem arises due to the `GestureRecognizer` Cleanup -
[Here  is the documentation if you are intrested in the migration code](http://OneSequenceGestureRecognizer.addAllowedPointer()%20was%20changed%20to%20take%20a%20PointerDownEvent,%20like%20it%20superclass.%20Previously,%20it%20accepted%20the%20more%20general%20PointerEvent%20type,%20which%20was%20incorrect.)

But in case you just want to build your flutter app without any migrations following are couple of solutions to that problem

1. You can update `photo_view` dependency in your `pubspec.yaml`     file to
   `photo_view :^0.12.0`
2. If you do not want to update your dependency due to any reason you can opt for this temporary fix . In the `pubspec.yaml` file add the following     custom photo_view with better gesture recognition in dependency_overrides.

dependency_overrides:

```
   photo_view:
     git: git://github.com/robertodoering/photo_view.git
```